# Trouble integrating a nested for and if loops in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a simulation of a library check in/checkout system. I have all the objects made but am having trouble with the loop that performs the simulation itself. My code:

The pseudo code:

```
//while loop or for loop for 90 days
      //For loop over catalog
         //forloop over patrons 
             //Check if available , if so check book out
             //If not available check book back in
                 //check checking back in check to see if book is overdue and if so add a fine
    //When down loop over patrons to see their fees
```

My try at that loop

```
for (var j = 0; j < 90; j++) {            
    for (var i = 0; i < catalog.length; i++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < patrons.length; k++) {
            if (books[k].Available = true) {
                books[k].checkOut = true; }
                else {
                    books[k].Available = true;
                }
                if (books[k].isOverdue = true) {
                    fine = fine + 5.00;
                }
            }
        }
        patrons[j].fine = fine;
        j++;
    }
```

All the code

```
    var Book = function(title, Available, publicationDate, checkoutDate, callNumber, Authors) {
    this.title = title;
    this.Available = Available;
    this.publicationDate = publicationDate;
    this.checkoutDate = checkoutDate;
    this.callNumber = callNumber;
    this.Authors = Authors;
};

var Author = function(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
};

var Patron = function(firstName, lastName, libCardNum, booksOut, fine) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.libCardNum = libCardNum;
    this.booksOut = booksOut;
    this.fine = fine;
};

Book.prototype.checkOut = function() {
    this.Available = false;
    var temp = new Date(1000000000);
    var date = new Date() - temp;
    var res = new Date(date);
    this.checkoutDate = res;
};

Book.prototype.isOverdue = function() {
    var singleDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var todayDate = new Date().getTime();
    var difference = todayDate - this.checkoutDate.getTime();
    if (Math.round(difference / singleDay) >= 14) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

Patron.prototype.read = function(book) {
    this.booksOut.add(book);
}

Patron.prototype.read = function(book) {
    this.booksOut.remove(this.booksOut.length);
}

var authors = [];
authors[0] = new Author("Auth", "One");
authors[1] = new Author("AutL", "Two");

var catalog = [];
catalog[0] = new Book('Bk1', true, new Date(2001, 1, 21), new Date(), 123456, authors);
catalog[1] = new Book('Bk2', true, new Date(2002, 2, 22), new Date(), 987656, authors);
catalog[2] = new Book('Bk3', true, new Date(2003, 3, 23), new Date(), 092673, authors);
catalog[3] = new Book('Bk4', true, new Date(2004, 4, 24), new Date(), 658342, authors);
catalog[4] = new Book('Bk5', true, new Date(2005, 5, 25), new Date(), 345678, authors);

var patrons = [];
patrons[0] = new Patron('Pat1', 'Wat', 1, catalog, 0.00);
patrons[1] = new Patron('Pat2', 'Wot', 1, catalog, 0.00);
patrons[2] = new Patron('Pat3', 'Wit', 1, catalog, 0.00);
patrons[3] = new Patron('Pat4', 'Wet', 1, catalog, 0.00);
patrons[4] = new Patron('Pat5', 'Wut', 1, catalog, 0.00);

var j = 0;

//while loop or for loop for 90 days
  //For loop over catalog
     //forloop over patrons 
         //Check if available , if so check book out
         //If not available check book back in
             //check checking back in check to see if book is overdue and if so add a fine
//When down loop over patrons to see their fees

for (var j = 0; j < 90; j++) {            
    for (var i = 0; i < catalog.length; i++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < patrons.length; i++) {
            if (books[i].Available = true) {
                books[i].checkOut = true; }
                else {
                    books[i].Available = true;
                }
                if (books[i].isOverdue = true) {
                    fine = fine + 5.00;
                }
            }
        }
        patrons[j].fine = fine;
        j++;
    }

for (i = 0; i < patrons.length; i++) {
    console.log(patrons[i].firstName + " has checked out the following books:");
    for (j = 0; j < patrons[i].booksOut.length; j++) {
        console.log(patrons[i].booksOut[j].title);
    }
    console.log(patrons[i].firstName + " has fine amount: $" + patrons[i].fine);
}
```

Comment: You're using the same loop variable for two nested loops: that wont work...

Comment: @trincot Edited it in, but still gives the same output. Says ReferenceError: books is not defined

Comment: You never defined `books`, so what did you expect? You have a lot mixed up there: `patrons[j]` while `k` iterates over `patrons` indexes and `j` is going to 90? You don't have that many `patrons`. And `catalog` array has books, but you reference it as `books`, but not with the index that iterates over the `catalog` indexes .... hmmm. Maybe take a nap and start again? ;-)

Comment: Why don't you use a database? I don't think this script is very useful when items are hardcoded in javascript. Or is this just for practice?

Comment: You should be getting many errors in [your browser's console](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/2288/console#t=201704202141378233544&a=remarks). You should really learn to use that, and the debugger, so that you can answer these questions yourself.

Comment: @trincot I am not the best at loops, they always throw me for a loop. I will try to learn more about them. Appreciate the advice.

Comment: Could you explain the simulation itself in words? Beside all what I already mentioned, the (pseudo) code makes no sense: why would you need to iterate over each of 90 days? And why do you never reference the selected day in any of the code that follows, and why would you need to look at all combinations of books and patrons? This cannot be right. The `overdue` property is never changed. For every book that is available you set `checkOut` to true, and you do this several times for the same book, but never indicate which patron has it checked out, ...etc, ...etc. Better describe what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In your code change your duplicated variables names `i` and don't forget to add `var` to not make them global:

```
for (var j = 0; j < 90; j++) {            
    for (var i = 0; i < catalog.length; i++) {
        for (var n = 0; n < patrons.length; n++) {
            if (books[n].Available = true) {
                books[n].checkOut = true; }
                else {
                    books[n].Available = true;
                }
                if (books[n].isOverdue = true) {
                    fine = fine + 5.00;
                }
            }
        }
        patrons[j].fine = fine;
        j++;
    }

for (var i = 0; i < patrons.length; i++) {
    console.log(patrons[i].firstName + " has checked out the following books:");
    for (var j = 0; j < patrons[i].booksOut.length; j++) {
        console.log(patrons[i].booksOut[j].title);
    }
    console.log(patrons[i].firstName + " has fine amount: $" + patrons[i].fine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you second and third loops use the same iteration variable (i)

Perhaps use  different name